# What will happen if I have a non-clock-driven entity in VHDL while others are clock-driven?

Tags: vhdl

I am doing an assignment about creating an encrypt block with VHDL.
While doing this, I need to create several basic entities like xor or mux, which are described with process, and the clock signal is not included in the sensitivy list.
As an example for the MUX:

```
process(S,D0,D1)
begin 
    case S is
        when '0' =>
            O <= D0;
        when '1' =>
            O <= D1;
        when others =>
            O <= (others => 'X');
    end case;
end process;
```

Meanwhile, some other blocks use clk as the driven signal:
As the register:

```
process (Clock)
begin
    if (Clock='1' and Clock'EVENT )then
        if (ENABLE='1') then
            Q <= D;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Is this something legit? I think this is something we don't want in real design, am I correct?

It can pass the simulation and synthesis. But is it okay to do like this?

Comment: This models combinational logic and is legit.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly legit.

Components driven by a clock are [synchronous circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_circuit). According to the linked Wikipedia page:

> [...] a synchronous circuit is a digital circuit in which the changes in the state of memory elements are synchronized by a clock signal.

Components without a clock are [asynchronous circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_circuit). According to the linked Wikipedia page:

> The asynchronous circuits do not need a global clock, and the state of the circuit changes as soon as the inputs change.

You can mix both kinds of circuits in a design. Actually, if you look at a synchronous circuit as a [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), the combinational logic is an asynchronous circuit.

In your example of the clock-driven design, there is a multiplexer at the input of the flip-flop that stores the output value `Q`. It switches between `D` and (read back) `Q` by the selection input `ENABLE`.